# Button in Fragment's ListView item Interface Definition?

Tags: android, listview, button, interface, fragment

In my app, I have an activity that has two fragments in actionbar tabs navigation mode, just like the android developer site example.

in my first fragment I have a listview (which has it's own adapter ) and each item of the listview has a button called +1. I want to refresh the second fragment that shows the items in listview in first fragment that their +1 button's clicked.

I know i have to use interfaces. but I cant figure how to use them. where do I have to define the interface? how to use it? and how to access it from the activity to refresh the second fragment?

a quick help would be great. thanks.

Comment: Do you want to navigate to second fragment on click of a "button inside each listItem" or on click of each listItem using the Interface?

Comment: @Santhosh no, I want to add the item's button clicked (from first fragment) to show in second fragment's listview (by refreshing the second fragment, the data is pesisted in a file). meaning I have to communicate between the listview item's button inside first fragment and the activity containing these two fragments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it on List Item Click

Fragment A:

```
public class FragmentA extends ListFragment {

OnItemSelectedListener mListener;

...
// Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onItemSelected(int position);
}
...

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnItemSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    mCallback.onItemSelected(position);

    }   
}
```

ContainerActivity:

```
public class ContainerActivity extends FragmentActivity 
    implements FragmentA.OnItemSelectedListener
{

//...



public void onItemSelected(int Position/*pass anything which u want*/) 
    {

        SecondFragment second_fragment = (SecondFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentB);

        if(second_fragment !=null)
        {
            second_fragment.UpdateUI(Position); 
        }

    }


 }
```

Second Fragment:

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    ...
    public void UpdateUI(Position)
    {

    }

}
```

Hope this helps. On click of a Button inside each listitem might be bit difficult, but try the same approach. May be you have to write the interface declaration and call in your custom adapter.

Comment: I'll test this out. But I have to add this, the button clicked is in the listview item.so the interface declaration must be inside fragment scope or the adapter of the listview's scope? thanks

Comment: yes, that is what i think and suggest. But, i can't say for sure that it will work because i haven't worked on such requirement.

Comment: what about this: declare interface in listview adapter -> call it in hosting activity -> from there, call another method in the fragment? am I right?

Comment: Yes, declare interface in Adapter class. implement that in hosting activity and call the method on click of the button in each listitem (i.e in getView() method of the adapter). I was not able to login since two days, hence late reply. Hope you have solved your problem.