# Android - how to replace the fragment from within another fragment in a 3-pane landscape view

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an application using 3-pane view layout (a classic “master-detail” flow), following a 2-pane example created by [mobile tuts](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-using-fragments/) .

The 3-pane layout looks as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground"
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:showDividers="middle"
tools:context=".SListA" >

<!--
This layout is a three-pane layout for the 
master/detail flow. 
-->

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/s_list"
    android:name="com.xxxxx.xxxxxx.SListF"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/s_events"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/s_details"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" />
```

I have encountered a problem when trying to replace the third fragment panel in the above 3-pane view (in wide/landscape tablet mode). The error is in the last line of code below, to be executed from the middle panel fragment code:

```
    @Override  
    public void setEventKey(String event_key) {
        if (SListA.m3Pane) {                                
            // In three-pane mode, show the details view in this activity by
            // adding or replacing the details fragment using a
            // fragment transaction.
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putString(SDetailsF.ARG_EVENTKEY, event_key);
            SDetailsF fragment = new SDetailsF();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.s_details, fragment).commit();
    }
```

The last line of code above shows a compile error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   getFragmentManager() from the type Fragment

(Note, I have set the minSdkVersion=11).
An identical code is used to replace the fragment for the second (middle) panel, and I don't understand why it is not working for the third panel. The only difference is, that the replace fragment code for the second (middle) panel is run from within the (first panel) activity code, instead of the (second panel) fragment code.

I was able to replace the above problem code with the following code, without getting the compile error:

```
                fragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.s_details, fragment).commit();
```

however, this code crashes when executed during the run with an InvocationTargetException message:

"Source not found"

Any ideas how to correct this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The correct way of replacing a fragment is from the parent activity, and not from another fragment. As Santosh correctly said, you need to add an interface to your fragment, which should be implemented by the parent activity to be able to handle events generated by the fragment. You can find this method properly explained [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use interfaces. whenever you need to communicate between fragments you must declare an interface in each fragment and that interface has to be implemented by the activity holding it. then on some event within the fragment, you call the method implemented by the activity. and then in that method you carry on neccesary action(in your case to  change/replace the fragment) which must reflect in other fragments.

Check this answer of mine. its similar to which you have to follow.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/15296370/1567588

Comment: This is exactly what I have been missing.  The final solution was to add a second item: implements FragmentB.Callbacks to the main activity class and then direct this callback from the FragmentB to the new OnItemSelected method in the main activity (which then replaces the updated FragmentC in tablet mode).  My 3-pane view now works perfectly well, both in the landscape (tablet) mode, as well as in the portrait (single pane) mode, where it uses 3 separate activities connected to 3 separate fragments. Your prompt assistance was very helpful and is most appreciated. Thank you!