# How Fragment implement interfaceListener android

Tags: android, interface, fragment

I have one activity which contains buttons if I click any button according to that in my fragment layout changes should happen.
for this I created a interface it has one method public void onclick();
fragment implementing interface it got onclick method. I created reference to interface in activity I am calling this method from activity but not calling onclick in fragment plz help

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15296370/1567588. let me know if u need any specific help..

Comment: Fragment should implement interface listener not activity

Comment: if activity implements interface then method in interface override I need same thing in Fragment. if fragment implements interface then method override.If I call that method from activity then it should called

Comment: interface S{  void click();}  class R extends Activity{  S s;   s.click(); }  class Fragment activity extends Fragment implements S{  click(){} }