# Android callback from activity to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, callback

I have "onOptionsItemSelected" method overrided in main activity, i want to notify my list when i tap on action bar items to change language on list. how do i make callback from MainActivity.java to my ListFragment.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_exit) {
        finish();

        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.action_en) {
        changeLanguageToEn();

        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.action_ge) {
        changeLanguageToGe();

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your fragment is called `MyListFragment.java` and has a method called `changeLanguage()` I usually use the following method to get the current fragment:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
// (if you're not using the support library)
// FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
for (Fragment fragment : fragmentManager.getFragments()) {
    if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible() && fragment instanceof MyListFragment) {
        ((MyListFragment) fragment).changeLanguage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i got it! i dont need Callback, I just called public methods to chage languages.

Answer (score 0):

Within your [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html), you can inflate a menu.

Answer (score 0):

You do this using the Activity - Fragment interface Listener pattern.
[android docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

to read more about it.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295581/button-in-fragments-listview-item-interface-definition/15296370#15296370)  they are doing opposite of what you are..fragment is callbacking to an activity, using same pattern.

you can also use FragmentManager and find said fragment and then call its public method
you can also TypeCast using getActivity and call activity methods from fragment. [but the interface pattern will solve and deouple your code nicely]

Comment: i tried that. i created Listener interface and Initialize on "onAttachFragment" method but i get null pointer exception "Attempt to invoke interface method 'void thevoid.com.bookapp.MainActivity$OnLanguageSelectedListener.onSelectGe()' on a null object reference"

Comment: if ya could put your code, id be happy to fix it for ye . edt:oh nvm youve solved it