# How to get value of a clicked item of a listview of a fragment in model view fragment of android, using java

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, viewmodel

I have a model view fragment which is having a list view and a textview.

What I am wanting, is, whenever an item of the list view is clicked, its clicked item will be shown in the textview.

### The following is the code of fragment_home.xml:-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment"
    android:background="@drawable/background">




    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_main"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:entries="@array/sections" >


    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

### Following is the code of HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HomeViewModel homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);


        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        final TextView textView = binding.textHome;
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), textView::setText);
```

---

### Following, is the code of HomeViewModel.java

```
public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<String> mText;

    ListView lv_main;
    ArrayList<String> items;

    public HomeViewModel() {
        mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
        

        lv_main.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
 
                mText.setValue(items.get(position));
            }
        });

    }

    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;
    }
}
```

---

Please let me know how it can be achieved and oblige me thereby.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using an interface, something like this: [calling click with interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15296370/18141665)

So, when item is clicked you send the value through the interface and show it in textview.